# What would cause a <div> to bunch up in the corner?

Tags: html, css

This worked fine on my test page. But when I put it on my boss's page, it bunches up in the top left corner!

```
#chatBox {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 125;
  left: 200;
  width: 400;
  height: 200;
  background-color: #8596C1;
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid 1px;
  display: none;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: No idea, what's your HTML look like?

Comment: You can view the whole thing here: http://www.mytrafficman.net/ask.php

Comment: It will be more helpful if you show a bit of ur HTML code which is using this id.

Comment: Works fine in Firefox, which browser does the chatbox appear in the left corner?

Answer (score 1):

You might have problems cross-browser because your "width" and "height" don't end in "px". See if that helps at all.